# I lied about how long I worked at a company and the background check people have emailed the company

Tags: resume, references

I live in the USA and moved here from abroad. I only recently got eligibility to work and so I have never had a job in the USA. The last thing I did in my country of origin before I moved here was a few weeks of admin work experience that was unpaid.

I graduated almost a year ago and I think due to not having work experience I have had no luck in that time getting an admin position. After a while I thought my only hope was to change the few weeks to a longer period and changed it to 2 years on my resume and started getting more calls back.

I have this one company (just a family run small business), offer me a job with them and they asked for work experience. I put that job on there but never put a number seems I didn't think they would call overseas. I did say yes to may we contact this employer though, but never thought they would seems they told me they don't call overseas.

So the background check company they hired called me yesterday to say they couldn't call the company as it was overseas but they emailed them and are waiting to hear back.

I know what I did was wrong, but I was desperate to get a job and I am not sure whether I should just pray they don't get back (or do respond back but say they have no record of me being there), as that is better than them coming back and straight up saying I only worked there a few weeks. Does anyone have good suggestions of what the best thing is I should do?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: The best thing twould have been not to lie tHis time, and not to lie next time. Whatever you do, you've cheated yourself out of this job.

Comment: I would worry more about immigration as you might of lied to them too.

Comment: just want to add this on top of the answers: they'll probably figure it out soon anyway. There is a HUGE difference between worked 2 years at a role and a few weeks. Don't do this, it'll eventually blow up and hurt your career at some stage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover from using a fake resume during my career?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/28373/how-do-i-recover-from-using-a-fake-resume-during-my-career)

Answer (score 10):

Honestly, you messed up. You lied and have a high chance of being caught in that lie. I know it is tough to get calls when you have minor work experience but you have to just keep trying until it happens. Most people struggle when they start out and it's normal. I know it sucks but it is better than being caught in a lie and possibly blacklisted from that company forever.

I would keep putting out CVs (after removing the lie) where you are and hope for the best. This background company may come back and say they couldn't get a hold of anyone or they may come back and disclose your lie but you don't know. Play it safe and keep looking.

Comment: For that matter, _always_ keep looking until you havd a solid, unconditional written offer.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah it is tough not getting work but this is much worse. I was hoping they just came back and said i did work there once but don't disclose the time period, or just said they have no record of it. I am not sure honestly though if saying they have no record of me working there will help me

Comment: If they said they had no record of you it's just like saying you worked for only two weeks. You will still be caught in a lie. Keep looking mate and don't make this mistake again.

Comment: I don't actually think my home country keep records of work experience people anyway, only proper employees, not sure if it would make much difference at this point though

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I edited the post to include that. Thank you

Comment: @jules85 even worse than not getting this job, it's likely your attempt at fraud will get passed around among HR managers and recruiters, causing you trouble getting hired elsewhere as well. Too late now to do anything about it, except possibly coming clean.

Answer (score 4):

You've already thrown the dice, nothing positive you can do except relax and see what happens, if you get caught you get caught. Keep trying to find a job elsewhere anyway. Telling them you lied is not going to help you, so best to do nothing.

If they come straight out and ask you, then tell the truth, explain that it was the only way people were responding to your applications and you're desperate for work. Either they'll let it slide (unlikely) or they won't. But too late to worry about it now.

In the future just have a truthful resume.

Comment: admitting he lied MAY prevent the people involved warning colleagues elsewhere about him...

Comment: @jwenting true, I tried to cover that in my second paragraph. To come out and admit it before anyone asks may or may not, there's no way of telling. I would wait until asked. Because I know it wouldn't stop me mentioning it to colleagues. Whereas if I asked and the OP owned up immediately I would look at it in a better light. Doesn't mean I'd hire him though. I just like people that won't lie to a direct question. Everyone makes mistakes especially inexperienced ones.